# How to sort rich text box in ascending order using c#

Tags: c#

I want get out put like 1.2.3.4.5.. but in this code I got values like 1,10,100,101..  plz help me friends

```
private void btn_load_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    {
        if (textBox1.Text != "")
        {
            richTextBox1.Clear();
            string tt = @"" + textBox1.Text;
            String sdira = @"" + textBox1.Text;
            string[] arrays = Directory.GetFiles(sdira, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
              .Select(x => Path.GetFileName(x))
              .ToArray();// get only file name and extention
            foreach (string name in arrays)
            {
                //StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                richTextBox1.Text += name + "\n";
                //i want get out put like 1.2.3.4.5.. 
                //but in this code i got values like 1,10,100,101.. 
                //plz help me friends[first img is my current out put][1]
            }
        }
    }
```

[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JW8C.png)

Comment: what does textbox1.text contains ? ()

Comment: You should sort the data first, then append the items to a `StringBuilder`, and finally add the result to the `RichTextBox`.

Comment: textbox1.text is the path

Answer (score 0):

If you want sort the strings  as numbers instead of  lexicographically you have to parse them:

```
var orderedFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(sdira, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .Select(x => new { file = x, nameNumber = Path.GetFileName(x).TryGetInt32() })
    .Where(x => x.nameNumber.HasValue)
    .OrderBy(x => x.nameNumber.Value)
    .Select(x => x.file); // or x.nameNumber.Value is you want the number
```

Here's the parse extension method is use in LINQ queries:

```
public static int? TryGetInt32(this string item, IFormatProvider formatProvider = null, NumberStyles nStyles = NumberStyles.Any)
{
    if (formatProvider == null) formatProvider = NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo;
    int i = 0;
    bool success = int.TryParse(item, nStyles, formatProvider, out i);
    if (success)
        return i;
    else
        return null;
}
```